# Markov's inequality

Tags: measure-theory

I need to prove that a measure µ on X is σ-finite if and only if there is a A-B(R¯)-measurable function
$f : X → [0, ∞]$ with$\int_X
f dµ < ∞\;and\; f(x) > 0 \;for\; all\; x ∈ X.$
So I recognise that I need to use Markov’s inequality for at least a part of the proof, but not sure how, if anyone can help it will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If part: $\mu (\{x: f(x) >n\} \leq \frac 1 n \int fd\mu<\infty$ for every $n$ and $X=\bigcup_n \{x: f(x) >n\} \bigcup \{x: f(x)=\infty\}$. Also, the last set has measure $0$ so $\mu$ is $\sigma-$ finite.

Only if part: Suppose $X=\bigcup_n A_n$ with $\mu (A_n) <\infty$ for each $n$. We may suppose $\mu(A_n) >0$ for all $n$. Take $f(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_n\chi_{A_n}$ where $a_n=2^{-n}(\mu(A_n))^{-1}$. Then $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ and  $\int f d\mu<\infty$.